# When using BEM, is it illogical to have a block nested inside its element?

Tags: css, naming-conventions, bem

Let's say I want to have a `title` block, and for styling considerations I need to nest it inside a `div` with some special CSS styling (e.g. I want specific border and spacing styling). Let's call this one `box`. The box just serves the style the `title` inside it.

The fact I need to have `box` at all just has to do with the limitations of CSS, so it doesn't make sense for the `box` to be considered a block in BEM terminology. It doesn't even make sense as a DOM element. But `title` is located inside `box`.

It makes sense to me to give `box` the class `title__box` because it doesn't make sense without `title`. However, all examples of BEM seem to assume the element is always a DOM child of the block it's in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question plainly without investigating further into this, no.
You would have to have something like the following

```
<div class="decorator">
  <h1 class="title">blah blah</h1>
</div>
```

or

```
<div class="title">
  <h1 class="title__heading">blah blah</h1>
</div>
```

When using BEM you have to think in terms of "blocks", "elements" and their reusability. In particular, consider this from a developer perspective: you don't want to end up in a particular scenario where the developer will build the title in question and forget an element or an attribute and get mad trying to figure out why it doesn't work. This gives you consistency and replicability of your markup.

I have no specific insight on *why* you need the `<div>` and what are the CSS *limitations* that you're talking about, but I will take your word for it.

So I'm going to ask: have you thought of cleaning up the markup using pseudo selectors, or using the heading as the aforementioned container and using inline anonymous elements (i.e. `<span>`s)?

I hope this helps solving your problems.